# can IWP be enabled with a filemaker pro 12 advanced runtime?

Tags: filemaker

Just as the title states,...
 Is it possible to enable Instant Web Publishing in a runtime created in Filemaker Pro 12 Advanced?

Looking to create a LAN/Internet accessible filemaker file for a small group of 8 individuals.
In our case, Version 13 did away with IWP, and the server pricing is just too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

No. The runtime application cannot share files in any way or form.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime applications cannot be shared over a network and do not include the ability to Save/Send Records as Adobe PDF files. ODBC import, the Execute SQL script step, and using ODBC data sources in the relationships graph are not supported in runtime application. For a feature comparison of the runtime application with FileMaker Pro, see the FileMaker Pro Advanced Development Guide at www.filemaker.com/documentation.

Read more [here](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/fmpa_tools.24.12.html)